# Tengo problemas para mostrar el formato de etiqueta que necesito

Tags: javascript, plugin, charts

necesito mostrar esto en mi gráfico de barras y no pude lograr configurar el complemento de charts js datalabel-plugin, tengo un api de donde me llegan los datos, el ultimo arreglo de datos "porcentaje" debe mostrarse cada uno de esos valores cada 30 días del total de 360 días que tiene el gráfico.
Les agradecería muchísimo su ayuda. 
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```js
var XValues = [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
  45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65,
  66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86,
  87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
  106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121,
  122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137,
  138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153,
  154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169,
  170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185,
  186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201,
  202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217,
  218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233,
  234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249,
  250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265,
  266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281,
  282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297,
  298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313,
  314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329,
  330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345,
  346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360
];

var YValues = [
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50000.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1220779.6, 130000.0, 296000.0, 1162027.14, 0.0, 0.0, 2768482.84,
  373769.69, 3266877.14, 954752.3, 0.0, 2179743.89, 1119815.91, 0.0, 1546573.58,
  2295188.35, 5766416.61, 2400059.89, 1362544.32, 2065125.0, 0.0, 2614227.3, 4312441.03,
  1567752.45, 396385.85, 784367.19, 1251550.85, 649401.57, 1960851.15, 2418563.82,
  5763793.94, 770000.0, 200000.0, 1000000.0, 489582.34, 8701720.72, 4233160.43, 0.0,
  800000.0, 3275422.23, 0.0, 0.0, 10834000.0, 9480157.63, 5458915.89, 1248660.23,
  3076394.38, 0.0, 1248800.0, 1300000.0, 3239404.21, 4721667.16, 6325239.51, 723000.0,
  120500.0, 0.0, 2700856.83, 300000.0, 6085455.79, 12365548.65, 250000.0, 2275793.87,
  816111.3, 2312688.39, 1193043.0, 1684344.47, 650000.0, 2970000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 814123.8,
  3000000.0, 1482929.54, 1597000.0, 2145474.31, 883611.12, 0.0, 1344585.29, 2223230.0,
  2906253.0, 1478849.38, 1100001.0, 0.0, 500347.76, 0.0, 0.0, 1002860.0, 1378000.0, 2300000.0,
  0.0, 672000.0, 12794114.88, 0.0, 1533827.5, 320000.0, 2214936.52, 0.0, 0.0, 2183429.87, 1200000.0,
  2215000.0, 800000.0, 959169.9, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 864901.01, 650000.0, 650000.0, 20000.0,
  300000.0, 239289.19, 0.0, 200000.0, 2963732.7, 0.0, 20000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 611631.66, 300000.0,
  0.0, 250000.0, 250000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 622281.05, 0.0, 20000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  758217.94, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2250000.0, 337580.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  150000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 855543.06, 36700.0, 0.0, 370000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 200000.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 130000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
];

var porcentajes = [30, 8, 10, 6, 3];

var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("sub"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: XValues,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Cheques",
      data: YValues,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(100,100,200, .4)",
      borderColor: "rgba(100,100,200, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1.5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(t, d) {
          return d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label
        },
        afterLabel: function(t, d) {
          return [t.xLabel + " Días", "$ " + t.yLabel.toLocaleString('es-AR')];
        },
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return;
        },
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{

        barThickness: 3,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 5,

          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 12
        },

        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          fontSize: 8,
          labelString: 'Vencimiento (dias)'
        },

      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          fontSize: 8,
          labelString: 'Importe ($)'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(label, index, labels) {
            if (label == 0) {
              return "   0";
            }
            if (label >= 1 && label <= 9) {
              return "     " + label;
            }
            if (label >= 10 && label <= 99) {
              return "   " + label;
            }
            if (label >= 100 && label <= 999) {
              return " " + label;
            }
            if (label >= 1000 && label <= 9999) {
              return "   " + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "K";
            }
            if (label >= 10000 && label <= 99999) {
              return " " + (label + "").slice(0, 2) + "K";
            }
            if (label >= 100000 && label <= 999999) {
              return "0." + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 1000000 && label <= 9999999) {
              return "   " + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 10000000 && label <= 99999999) {
              return " " + (label + "").slice(0, 2) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 100000000 && label <= 999999999) {
              return (label + "").slice(0, 3) + "M";
            }
            if (label >= 1000000000 && label <= 9999999999) {
              return " " + (label + "").slice(0, 1) + "mM";
            }
            if (label >= 10000000000 && label <= 99999999999) {
              return (label + "").slice(0, 2) + "mM";
            }
          }
        },

      }]
    },

    Plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        aling: 'end',

      }
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--Boostrap Styles-->
  <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/myCustomStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <canvas id="sub" height="100"></canvas> <!-- Bar chart-->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="lib/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>


    <!-- <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>     -->
    <!-- <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   -->

  </body>

</html>
```

Fiddle original:
https://jsfiddle.net/xqp2s567

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflowES ! Tu pregunta quedaria mucho mejor si compartes el código en lugar de poner un enlace ya que este puede dejar de estar operativo o no ser accesible ademas de que tu pregunta quedaria mejor visualmente ya que solo tienes una foto. Un saludo :)

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por el consejo, es mi primera pregunta y pense que pegue correctamente el link del jsfield.